# How to listen on all component events?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

The grid component `grid.js`:

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    ...
    <component v-for="c in cells" :is="c.componentName"></component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      cells: { type: Array, required: true }
    }
    methods: {
      // the idea what I need
      reEmitAllCellComponentEventWithPrefix($event) {
        // add prefix
        this.$emit("cell-" + $event.name, $event.data);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The base-cell component `base-cell.js` (define common cell props and methods):

```
export default {
  props: ['componentName', 'columnIndex', 'rowIndex', 'cellData', ...],
  ...
}
```

The custom-cell component `custom-cell.js` (all extend from base-cell component, register global):

```
<template>
  <dom ...>
</template>
<script>
  import baseCell from "./base-cell"
  export default {
    extends: baseCell,
    props: {
      componentName: '...',
      customProp1: '...',
      ...
    },
    watch: {
      // a custom event example
      customProp1(){
        this.$emit('custom-event1', ...)
      }
    },
    ...
  }
</script>
```

> All the cell components has its own custom events, maybe any event-name.

The usage:

```
// dom
<div id="app">
  <grid :cells="cells" @cell-custom-event1="customCellEventHandler"></grid>
</div>

// js
import grid from "./grid"
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { cells: ... },
  method: {
    customCellEventHandler($event){
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

I wanna user can listen on cell component's custom event with prefix `cell-` when use grid component. How can I make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I see the method is not used anywhere. Do you want all events to be triggered at once?

Comment: I wanna re-emit all child components event with a specific prefix. The method `reEmitAllCellComponentEvent` is just an idea, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <component v-for="c in cells" :is="c.componentName" @click="onClick(c.name, c.data)"></component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      cells: { type: Array, required: true }
    }
    methods: {
      onClick(name, data) {
        this.$emit("cell-" + name, data);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Basically when you look through the cells and create the elements, you add a click event for each cell and add whatever parameters you want, and use them to emit the event.
If you also need the "event" data you can add `$event` in `@click="onClick(c.name, c.data)"` like this `@click="onClick(c.name, c.data, $event)"` and then you can add on the method the respective paramater `onClick(name, data, e)`

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: This way just re-emit `click` event not all event from cell component. The cell component maybe has its own event design, and we don't know its event name.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  When you click on the cell, you emit a custom event called `cell-name` the name being whatever system you got there containing the passed data. As i said you can also pass `$event` if you require that. Does the Cell component also emits a custom event ( opposite to a click event)? Is that the issue?

Comment: What I need is not about transport event-data, is about bubble up the cell custom event to parent component with a prefix name. So user can listen on it on the parent component. I modified my question to make it more clear. Please check it again.